# Critical timing with GTK

Tags: gtk3, glib

I would like to set up time-critical timing on GTK. It's very important that the functions are called ON TIME. Moreso than even drawing the GUI. However, neither g_timeout_add, nor g_idle_add, are precise enough. "Note that timeout functions may be delayed, due to the processing of other event sources. Thus they should not be relied on for precise timing. After each call to the timeout function, the time of the next timeout is recalculated based on the current time and the given interval (it does not try to 'catch up' time lost in delays)." And the fact that idle functions are only called when nothing else is happening.

I have been considering a separate thread just for timing, are there any other options?

Comment: Define ‘on time’. What precision and accuracy do you want, what for, and why?

Comment: Well, my application is a GUI that controls valve operations that should be accurate to 0.05 seconds. Right now, with an timeout function, I can manage 0.15 seconds, moreover, It adds up overtime. I'm using a timeout functions that runs every 10 milliseconds. This is no good for my purpose, and this is critical since it means that people might get hurt

Comment: @Whiteclaws then you **must** use hard real time OS, as soft RTOS doesn't guarantee that your yask will really be called every 10 ms.

Comment: If a software failure has the potential to cause injury, you should seriously rethink your system. Design the hardware to fail safe for all failure modes of the software. If you absolutely must, control the timing using a dedicated microcontroller running a minimal amount of code, and control that via a message-passing interface to a separate (non-timing-critical) processor which is running the GUI.

Do not ever run GUIs on the same processor/memory bus as safety critical hardware. Any bug in the 15+ million lines of code for Linux + drivers + GTK+ could disrupt your controller.